# How to pass TestRunParameters to "dotnet test" command directly from command line

Tags: testing, .net-core, command-line, mstest

Below is runsettings files, having custom parameters defined.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RunSettings>
      <TestRunParameters>
        <Parameter name="publishResults" value="true" />
      </TestRunParameters>
    </RunSettings>
```

This is how I run command from command line
*dotnet test MyTests --settings develop.runsettings --no-build*

I want to avoid .runsettings and like to run like this
*dotnet test MyTests --publishResults true --no-build*

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, but your syntax is incorrect. From [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test?tabs=netcore21#options) documentation, you would call it like so:

```
dotnet test MyTests --no-build -- publishResults=true
```

Observe that the RunSettings argument is the *last* passed-in argument. Also observe that there is a space between the `--` and the `publishResults=true`. This space specifies that arguments that come afterward are used for RunSettings.